# Are European Union parallel multilingual texts ideal for machine learning of machine translation?

Tags: computational-linguistics, translation, machine-translation, computer-science

Are European Union parallel multilingual texts - regulations, directives, especially the debates of European parliament - ideal for machine learning of machine translation, e.g. with neural networks? My guess is that they are ideal, but I have not seen they to be used in actual research papers. If not, then - why they can not be ideal?

I am specifically interested in the grammar induction as the by-product of the machine translation learning a la https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10850 .

Answer (score 5):

Europarl *is* a classic corpus for research papers, used at the main conference - WMT - and by some of the top people in the field.

[image]

It would be useful for training a translation system specifically for European parliament domain.

But Europarl, like any domain-specific corpus, is *not* ideal for training a production-strength open-domain machine translation system.

How many times do the top queries like *how r u* or *ai eu se te pego* in the corpus?  To say nothing of *laham taz-ziemel* or *gradient descent*.

Comment: Now that I’ve googled what *laħam taż-żiemel* means, I think it may very well appear in some EU regulation, just like many other food items do.

Comment: You can Google *site:europarl.europa.eu "laham taz-ziemel"`, no results.  If you replace with with *parmesan* or *cognac* you will see get results.